# Starting a method in a thread, then changing the variables and starting a second thread of that method

Tags: android, multithreading, class, methods, multiple-instances

im trying to use `setLv1Sunflower()` to start a new thread, which shows a plant grow where ever the player picks. after pressing the seed button, the player picks which `placeHolder*` that the plant will start to grow. i have this for each plant position eg `placeHolder1(), placeHolder2()` and so on.

```
//PLACE HOLDER ONCLICK SHOWS INFO ON PLANT OR IF WATERMODEON IS TRUE SHOWS FOUND ANIMAL OR NO ANIMAL
    public void placeHolder1(View view){
        if (waterModeOn == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), placeHolder1ToastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (seedModeOn == true){
            showSeedMenu();
            selectedPlantImage = placeHolder1Image;
            selectedPlantToastMsg = placeHolder1ToastMsg;
            selectedPlantFoundAnimal = placeHolder1FoundAnimal;
            selectedPlantFullyGrown = plant1FullyGrown;

        }
        else{
            showFoundAnimalDialog();
        }
    }
```

then this starts whichever plant they pic, atm only have one set up

```
//SETS A NEW PLANT TO A PLACE HOLDER
    public void showSeedMenu(){

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Lv1 SunFlower", "Lv1 Daisy", "Lv1 Violet"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick A Seed");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                 if (item == 0){
                     Lv1Seeds.setLv1Sunflower();

                 }
                 seedModeOn = false;
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

this is `Lv1Seeds.class`

```
package com.gameplay.mysticgarden;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

    //LEVEL 1 SEED VALUES FOR PLACE HOLDERS
    public class Lv1Seeds extends Activity {



//INTS FOR LOOPS
    final static int a = 1;
    final static int b = 2;

    //LV1 SUNFLOWER VALUES
    public static void setLv1Sunflower(){

        GameScreen.selectedPlantFoundAnimal = false;
          GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.plant_stage1);
             GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //FIRST THREAD TO START
        /*Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {*/

             //2 LINES OF TEST CODE
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                  //UDATE UI STAGE 1 OF PLANT AND SETS TOAST MSG WHILE PLANT IS SEEDLING
                  while (a < b){
                      //SETS ANIMAL TO GONE FOR WHEN LOOP STARTS AGAIN
                      GameScreen.selectedPlantFoundAnimal = false;
                    //IF PLANT IS NOT FULLY GROWN UPDATE UI AND TOAST FOR SEEDLING STAGE
                        if (GameScreen.selectedPlantFullyGrown == false){
                            GameScreen.selectedPlantToastMsg = "Lv1 Seedling Sunflower \\(Sunnious Brightium\\) \nWill Attract Bee's!";
                        }
                  //WAIT 20 SECONDS
                  //CHANGE OF VALUES MAKES SEEDLING STAGE LAST LONGER
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 10 * 1);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  //UPDATE UI TO STAGE 2 OF PLANT
                  GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //IF PLANT IS NOT FULLY GROWN UPDATE UI AND TOAST FOR STAGE 2
                        if (GameScreen.selectedPlantFullyGrown == false){
                        GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.plant_stage_2);
                        GameScreen.selectedPlantToastMsg = "Lv1 Half Grown Sunflower \\Sunnious Brightium\\ \nWill Attract Bee's!";
                        }
                    }
                  });
                  //WAIT 20 SECONDS
                  //CHANGE OF VALUE MAKES STAGE 2 LAST LONGER
                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000  * 10 * 1);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  //UPDATE UI TO FULLY GROWN PLANT
                  GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        //IF PLANT IS NOT YET FULLY GROWN UPDATE UI AND TOAST FOR FULLY GROWN PLANT AND SETS plantFullyGrown TO TRUE
                        if (GameScreen.selectedPlantFullyGrown == false){
                        GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.flower_daisy);
                        GameScreen.selectedPlantToastMsg = "Lv1 Sunflower \\(Sunnious Brightium\\) \nWill Attract Bee's!";
                        GameScreen.selectedPlantFullyGrown = true;
                        }
                        //USED WHEN PLANT IS FULLY GROWN
                        else{
                            GameScreen.selectedPlantToastMsg = "Lv1 Sunflower \\(Sunnious Brightium\\) \nWill Attract Bee's!";
                            }
                        }
                      });
                      //WAIT 20 SECONDS
                      //CHANGE OF VALUES MAKE TIME LONGER BEFORE ANIMAL COMES, ONCE PLANT IS FULLY GROWN
                      try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000  * 10 * 1);
                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                   //SETS ANIMAL IN GARDEN
                   GameScreen.selectedPlantImage.post(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          GameScreen.selectedPlantFoundAnimal = true;
                      }
                   });
                   //ANIMAL STAYS FOR THIS TIME PERIOD
                   //CHANGE OF VALUE MAKES ANIMAL STAY LONGER
                        try {
                              Thread.sleep(1000  * 10 * 1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                  }
              }

    }).start();
          //END OF SUNFLOWER()  
          }

    //END OF CLASS  
    }
```

when the second plant is started, `setLv1Sunflower()` doesnt start a new instance of this method pland 1 stop doing anything and the second plant just carries on from where the first plant was up to in the method

this is my problem.....the first plant should keep growing, while the second plant starts off new

xml for gamescreen is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sun_1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/waterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/water_drop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waterPoints"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/waterButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/waterButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placedHolder1Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/placedHolder2Image"
        android:background="@drawable/blackspaceflower"
        android:onClick="placeHolder1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placedHolder2Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/placedHolder3Image"
        android:background="@drawable/blackspaceflower"
        android:onClick="placeHolder2"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placedHolder3Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blackspaceflower"
        android:onClick="placeHolder3"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placedHolder4Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placedHolder3Image"
        android:background="@drawable/blackspaceflower"
        android:onClick="placeHolder4"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placedHolder5Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placedHolder4Image"
        android:background="@drawable/blackspaceflower"
        android:onClick="placeHolder5"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:onClick="showSelectPlantDialog"
        android:text="@string/seeds" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i hope someone can please help me....your time is greatly appreciated

Comment: or is this just bad programming

Comment: what`s exactly your problem?

Comment: when 'setLv1Sunflower()' is called a second time, with differant 'selectedPlaceHolder*' values it carries on from the first time it was called